# How to create an image to unit test an API

Tags: python, django, rest, unit-testing

I have a simple model representing a female that a user can view, edit and create:

```
class Female(models.Model):

    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    profileImage = models.ImageField()
    bio = models.TextField()
    fantasticBio = models.TextField()
```

I am using a multi-part form to send the data for a create via an Angular service. This works fine. The django view that handles the creation is:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createFemale(request):

    serializedFemale = FemaleSerializer(data=request.data)

    if serializedFemale.is_valid():
        serializedFemale.save()
        return Response(serializedFemale.data)
    else:
        return Response(serializedFemale.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

My problem is that I am unable to fully unit test this view. I am having trouble creating an image that I can use to test the view via the test client. My knowledge of image generation is limited so I may be generating the image wrong, however it seems to be accepted as a Django ImageField when I write it directly to the database in my set up. The relevant test code is as follows:

```
def createImageFile():

    """
        Convinience function to create a test image
    """

    image = Image.new('RGBA', size=(50, 50), color=(256, 0, 0))
    image_file = BytesIO()
    image.save(image_file, 'PNG')
    img_str = base64.b64encode(image_file.getvalue())
    img_str = str.encode("data:image/png;base64,") + img_str

    return ImageFile(img_str)


def test_createFemale(self):

    """
        A valid Female created with the API should be in the database
    """

    profileImage = SimpleUploadedFile("test.png", createImageFile().file, content_type="image/png")

    femaleToCreate = {}
    femaleToCreate['firstName'] = "Test"
    femaleToCreate['lastName'] = "Female"
    femaleToCreate['profileImage'] = profileImage
    femaleToCreate['bio'] = "Test bio"
    femaleToCreate['fantasticBio'] = "Fantastic test bio"

    response = self.client.post(url, femaleToCreate)

    self.assertEquals(response.status_code, 200)  # Make sure valid request returns success response
```

The response I receive from the server is:

```
{'profileImage': ['Upload a valid image. The file you uploaded was either not an image or a corrupted image.']}
```

How can I create an image that will be accepted by my API from within my unit test?

Please refrain from suggesting a file read of an existing image, I have considered this option and chosen not to pursue it as I believe it is a bad practice.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why do you base64encode your image ?

Comment: @jmbarbier I saw it based64encoded when the browser was sending it so I tried that to see if it would help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I've got round this as follows:

```
def test_images_by_component_id_update(self):
    image = PIL.Image.new('RGB', size=(1, 1))
    file = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(suffix='.jpg')
    image.save(file)

    with open(file.name, 'rb') as f:
        data = {'image': f}
        response = self.client.patch(reverse('foo', args=(1, 1)), data=data, format='multipart')

    self.assertEqual(200, response.status_code)
```

Notice I have to reopen the file, this took a while to debug.  For whatever reason it doesn't like the NamedTemporaryFile.file attribute so I had to reopen.

Comment: Saved my day. With your example, I was able to create a test for my endpoint.

Comment: what is `tempfile` here?